# Block an app/add-in in Microsoft to restrict users to install

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365

I have a requirement to block a specific app/add-in from Microsoft. So that users will not be able to install the app/add-in in their office products(Office, Teams, Outlook, etc.). I have gone through documentation, but I saw only an option to disable add-ins, this will block all the add-ins for all the users which I don’t want.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/manage/manage-addins-in-the-admin-center?view=o365-worldwide

I also gone through Microsoft Graph APIs and I found an API to remove appRoleAssignment from users, but user can install again. I want to block the app permanently. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/approleassignment?view=graph-rest-1.0

If there is an option to block an app/add-in permanently please let me know.

Comment: You should try the following approach - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/manage/manage-addins-in-the-admin-center?view=o365-worldwide#prevent-add-in-downloads-by-turning-off-the-office-store-across-all-clients-except-outlook. This will work for you except Outlook. For Outlook, you can try this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/add-ins-for-outlook/specify-who-can-install-and-manage-add-ins?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Thanks Dev for your response. I tried disabling the Add-in(Status to Off) and tried to install in Teams and it allowed to install and access. The expectation should be not allowed to install the add-in

Comment: So you see the issue only with Microsoft Teams?

Comment: Dev, It is same issue with all office tools (word, Excel, PPT) as well

Comment: if you want to prevent add-in downloads by turning off the Office Store across Outlook then try the steps - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/add-ins-for-outlook/specify-who-can-install-and-manage-add-ins#prevent-add-in-downloads-by-turning-off-the-office-store-across-outlook

Comment: For Microsoft Teams you can use these policies -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-app-permission-policies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Conditional Access Policy we can block app(s) for the user(s) to authorize to use the app(s). Here is the documentation ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/conditionalaccesspolicy?view=graph-rest-1.0